# How to make psql completion with Windows?

Tags: windows, postgresql, psql

There is a completion function by the psql command of Cygwin or UNIX
There is not the function in psql for a Windows native.
How to make psql completion with  Windows?

Comment: Are you talking about autocompletion in the shell, or in the SQL prompt?

Answer (score 5):

Readline is disabled by default on Windows. You can rebuild with it enabled - but it is broken for most non-english locales. For example, in most western european locales you can no longer type backslash - an essential character to use readline. This is a bug in readline, but last time I checked they had zero interest in the win32 platform and won't fix it.

Answer (score 4):

It's now 2018 and I still haven't managed the tab completion to work on Windows.

But fortunately you can run psql in the Windows Subsystem for Linux on the latest Windows 10. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10
Tab completion works there.